# How can I sort a table by two columns in sisense?

Tags: sql, sorting, hyperlink, pivot, sisense

I use Sisense Version: 20.21.6.10054 on Windows.

I need to sort a table widget in sisense by two columns, first by name, and second by number of behavior that person demonstrates.

The result should look like this:

```
id   first_name   last_name   behavior_NO  behavior_link
1      Ben          Smith        1           behavior_1
1      Ben          Smith        2           behavior_2
1      Ben          Smith        3           behavior_3
2      Sam          Johns        1           behavior_1
2      Sam          Johns        2           behavior_2
3      Martha       Star         1           behavior_1
3      Martha       Star         2           behavior_2
3      Martha       Star         3           behavior_3
3      Martha       Star         4           behavior_4
```

Now, when I sort by Last_name the behavior_No is not sorted in correct order, but it looks like this:

```
id   first_name   last_name   behavior_NO   behavior_link
1      Ben          Smith        1            behavior_1
1      Ben          Smith        3            behavior_3
1      Ben          Smith        2            behavior_2
2      Sam          Johns        2            behavior_2
2      Sam          Johns        1            behavior_1
3      Martha       Star         4            behavior_4
3      Martha       Star         2            behavior_2
3      Martha       Star         1            behavior_1
3      Martha       Star         3            behavior_3
```

Sisense does not allow to sort by two columns in a table.

I tried to pivot the table but the problem is that there is a column with hyperlinks in it, and when making a pivot hyperlinks display like a text (<a href="https://https://stackoverflow.com/ ) but not like a link.

Can anyone advise on how to solve this, either to sort the table by two columns or to insert a hyperlink in a pivot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't link to images in your question - add the information as formatted text to your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already find a better way that the following but yesterday I had a requested to do a rank but also, ordering three columns. First I needed order by the Target then by Rank and then by Sales so in the pivot table can look like this:

```
Sales_Person | Target | Sales | Rank
   Joe       |  100%  |  12   |  1
   Chris     |  100%  |  12   |  1
   Maria     |  98%   |  11   |  2
   Peter     |  97%   |  10   |  3
```

So because Sisense in the front end does not allow to sort two or more columns there is a built-in function called "ORDERING".

In the following link you will find the function under "Other Functions"

[Function References Sisense](https://documentation.sisense.com/docs/function-references)

The only disadvantage is that at the time you implement this function it will create an additional column for ordering so at the end I obtained the following results:

```
Sales_Person | Target | Sales | Rank | Ordering
   Joe       |  100%  |  12   |  1   |    0
   Chris     |  100%  |  12   |  1   |    1
   Maria     |  98%   |  11   |  2   |    2
   Peter     |  97%   |  10   |  3   |    3
```

Also, keep in mind that all the different columns should be dimensions.

By the way, the version I have is Sisense **L2022.4.0.222**

Answer (score 0):

Just create the sort ordering column on the database side. Assuming the database is SQL based something like this would work.

```
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY first_name, last_name, behavior_NO) AS SortOrder
```

Put whatever columns you want to sort by after the ORDER BY and before the close parenthesis.

Then add that into the data model via a custom query.

This is extremely similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675094/3315862 but one layer back.